# How to evaluate this expression: $ \int\frac{\sin(2x)}{1+\cos(2x)}dx $

Tags: integration

$$
\int\frac{\sin(2x)}{1+\cos(2x)}dx
$$
Can anyone help me? I really could need some help whit this

Comment: Hint: let $u=1+\cos2x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $$(1+\cos(2x))'=-2\cdot \sin(2x)$$
with
$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\log|f(x)|+C.$$

Answer (score 2):

To solve this integral just apply several trig identities.

$\int\frac{\sin(2x)}{1+\cos(2x)}\mathrm{d}x = \int\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{1+2\cos^{2}(x)-1}\mathrm{d}x$ which simplifies to $\int \tan(x)\mathrm{d}x$ which I'm sure you can figure out.

Comment: $-\ln|\cos x|+C...$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use your double angle identities:
$$
\frac{\sin 2x}{1 + \cos 2x}
= \frac{2\sin x \cos x}{2\cos^2 x}
= \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}
$$
then use an appropriate $u$-substitution.

Comment: And what was the point of using double angle identities?

Comment: @Thursday I guess it wasn't necessary, in the sense that a $u$-substitution is still required to compute the integral. But I think  it makes the form of the final answer slightly simpler.